# Visual Studio can't see Codes

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a strange issue. 
After I publish my project and got back to solution again I found out my code dosent' work and when I get on code of some buttons I found methods like that.

```
 private void btnSave_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
//empty area  and there is same method without number 1 But it have my code 
                  }


 private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
//my code 
                  }
```

first: why does it happen ?
Second  : how can i solve it without copy and past ?

Comment: i make it as exe file 
if i understand u well

Comment: Does it work at debug time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like your button lots the connection to the `Click` handle `btnSave_Click` if you now double click your button in designer, it generates a new handler. Because `btnSave_Click` already exists, it creates `btnSave_Click_1`.

You can fix it by selecting your button in Designer, switch to the event tab, find the `Click` event and select in the dopdown next to it the method `btnSave_Click`

[image: Switching the Methode]

After this, you can delete the `btnSave_Click_1` method from your code.

Comment: but y it generates a new handler  even there was one and connected to the button  ?

Comment: It generates a new handler if none is connected with the button. When a Method with this name already exists VS begins counting, like you saw it at the empty Methode.

Comment: @AhmedRamadan If this answer had solved your proble, [you can accept it as the correct answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)